# varieties whose canonical bundle has finite order in Pic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a structure theorem for such varieties?

If X is a smooth and proper/projective variety whose canonical bundle $\omega_X$ has finite order in the Picard group, do we know anything about X?

EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments, if $\omega_X^n = O_X$ then one can find a cycling covering of order n, $Y \to X$, with $\omega_Y = O_Y$. So the problem reduces to understanding varieties with trivial canonical bundle. I'll leave the question as is for a few days more, in case someone else wants to contribute. If nothing happens I will delete it.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348105/why-do-varieties-with-torsion-canonical-sheaf-have-finite-etale-covers-with-triv

Comment: @dhy: thanks. I'll leave the question open but that may be as good as it gets.

Comment: See the article by Beauville 
"Variétés Kähleriennes dont la première classe de Chern est nulle".
J. Differential Geom. 18 (1983), no. 4, 755–782 (1984).

Comment: I'm not sure the problem fully reduces to understanding varieties with trivial canonical bundle, because you also need to understand what kind of quotients are possible. For example, suppose $Y$ is hyperkähler of dimension $2d$. Then Oguiso and Schröer showed (http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4912) that $n$ must divide $d+1$.

Comment: @ArtiePrendergast-Smith thanks, if you wrote even just that$+\epsilon$ as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Dear @user125763, unfortunately I don't think I know $\epsilon$ more to say...

Comment: @ArtiePrendergast-Smith: rats! I should have allowed $\epsilon = 0$!

Comment: @user125763: the idea that $\epsilon$ could be 0 is so amusing that I couldn't refuse your wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Comment copied here at user125763's request.)

There seem to be two parts to the problem.

The first part is the Bogomolov–Beauville theorem that any such variety $X$ has a finite étale cover $Y \rightarrow X$ such that $Y$ is a product of 1) "strict" Calabi–Yaus, 2) abelian varieties, and 3) hyperkähler varieties.

The second part is understanding what quotients are possible. For example, suppose Y is hyperkähler of dimension $2d$. Then Oguiso and Schröer showed ([arxiv.org/abs/1001.4912](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4912)) that the degree of the cover $Y \rightarrow X$ must divide $d+1$.